# Angular 6 ServiceWorker - index.html returned response 404 Not Found

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I've deployed PWA on my test server https://wwww.mytestserver.me/dev/pwa/ under 'dev/pwa' folder. The app passed Lighthouse with 100% PWA score. But the app still doesn't work as it's expected. It just doesn't work at all. )) JS console says:

> Failed to load ‘https://wwww.mytestserver.me/dev/pwa’. A ServiceWorker
>   passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with
>   ‘Error: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for
>   https://wwww.mytestserver.me/index.html returned response 404 Not
>   Found’ - ngsw-worker.js:589:31

In my manifest.json I have:   "scope": "/" and "start_url": "/". I tried to set them to https://wwww.mytestserver.me/dev/pwa/ and to just /dev/pwa/ but result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change **index** property in your **ngsw-config.json** from **/index.html** to **/dev/pwa/index.html**.

If this doesn't work, you need to clean browser caches. As for me it started to work only after complete clearing of browser data.