# Site can't be reached error-After hosting Angular app on IIS 8.0

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, web-hosting, angular-components

Recently I have hosted an angular(version 10) web app on our testing server (IIS 8.0). And also installed [URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS also.

And following is my web.config which was added for rules.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>        
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/index.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/index.html" />
    </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But after hosting the application the site is running but continuously getting following error **site can't be reached** as shown in below screen shot. After getting error the URL is automatically reloading within seconds and then site is working as expected.

Following is my app pool setting.

[image: App pool config]

What is the reason for this error ? It is happening without idle time also. Am I missing any IIS setting ? or need to add any other URL writing rule? or any settings need to included on my angular app? Please help me.

**[Update]**

With the help of debugging tools found that the error is in angular configuration files.

Comment: Learn the site bindings first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi i think default port 80 is disabled by the admin team. Will that be a problem? what is the fix for this any suggetions?

Comment: No suggestion might work unless your server administrators are involved. Ask them instead.

Comment: It may be caused by the cache, clear the cache and try again.

Comment: @samwu already tried after clearing cache and all no change

Comment: Then you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view specific content.

Comment: @samwu :what all status codes should be included for tracing ?

Comment: You can enter 100-599.

Comment: [https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7] check this

Comment: @ArokiaLijas: not able to view anything on the ur, it is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little bit of search and with the help of debugging tools finally able to fix the error. Changed the index property with application path in **ngsw-config.json**

```
"index": "YourAppPath/index.html"
```

Which solved the issue. More Details please go through angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config)

For details of error please go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170498/angular-6-serviceworker-index-html-returned-response-404-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things required:
first you need to install `url rewrite` by downloading from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

then you need to change your `web.config` file to redirect to `index.html` file to use angular 2 routing

this is `web.config` file you can use

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

nothing else is required. my site is also working with same way described above
my site is also in angular 10 Ivy

***one important thing also is that just give your site main folder permissions to everyone. This occurs for many developers as due to permissions site is unreachable***

Comment: i have already installed the url rewriting module and  even tried with above web.config but same result, and for site folder i have used an admin account in app pool